# Trying to install 3D Studio MAX 1.0 on Windows XP virtual machine, error: "Hardware drivers are not installed. Application will terminate"

Tags: windows-xp, version, 3ds-max

In an XP VM, following al tracker's instructions from here: https://vetusware.com/download/3ds%20Studio%20MAX%201.0/
in which the patch is applied, bypassing the dongle, but it still gives this error

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itZlU.png)

Comment: A virtual machine gets its drivers from the virtual machine App. What other drivers are you looking for.

Comment: A hardware driver for the dongle, but the patch is supposed to bypass it

Comment: Does your app support pass through?

Comment: I'm not sure, how could I find that out

Comment: What VM app are you using ?  My app (VMware) has removable devices under the VM tab.

Comment: I'm using VIrtualBox

Comment: Look for Removable Devices in the VBOX menu.

Comment: Yes I have that

Comment: Normally you would plug in the dongle and then see if Removable Devices will attach it to the Guest (XP) machine.

Comment: The only problem is they are very difficult to find